Deno: Use restricted network domains with Redis
Been having a good time trying out Deno and exploring the security/permissions system. I have a simple web application that connects to redis that I'm configuring a docker-compose setup.
The hostname in the container network is simply redis. When connecting to the redis container using the url redis://redis:6379, The deno application reports the error:
error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis

I have narrowed the problem and it appears to be due to me using the restrictive allow-net syntax to specifically allow through hosts. In my case, I want to let through the redis hostname.
CMD ["run", "--allow-net=redis:6379,[::]:8000", "--allow-env",  "--allow-read", "main.ts"]

If I change it to
CMD ["run", "--allow-net", "--allow-env",  "--allow-read", "main.ts"]

And allow any connections, the redis connection is succesfull. Is there an issue with the redis protocol being allowed by Deno when using the restrictive hostname syntax or is something else going on here?
Minimally reproducible example:
https://github.com/rphovley/docker-deno-redis

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]?

Yes, I'll get something up shortly

@jsejcksn updated with example. Thank you for taking a look!
